# How do I allocate memory for an array in the go programming language?

Tags: memory-management, go

I want to make an array of size N in go, but I don't know what N will be at compile time, how would I allocate memory for it?

e.g.

```
func MakeArray(size int) {
  return new ([size]int)
}
```

which doesn't work since size is not a constant.

This seems like a simple question, but I just started using go and it's not obvious to me how to do this from reading the tutorial (or searching the documentation for that matter).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The function `make` creates slices, maps, and channels, and it returns an initialized value of type T. The `make()` call allocates a new, hidden array to which the returned slice value refers.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){

   ptr := new(int)
   *ptr = 100

   fmt.Println("*ptr = ", *ptr)

   slice := make([]int, 10)    // slice with len(slice) == cap(slice) == 10

   for i:=0; i<len(slice); i++{
      fmt.Println(slice[i])
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, didn't realize 'make' had a second argument but 'new' doesn't.

Answer (score 10):

For slices, the Go [`make`](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Making_slices_maps_and_channels) built-in function has two or three arguments.

```
make(T, n)       slice of type T with length n and capacity n
make(T, n, m)    slice of type T with length n and capacity m
```